# qcc in R Studio, summary does not return sd

Tags: r

I have the following code;

```
ndata <- rnorm(n=1000,mean=0,sd=1)
qccobj<-qcc(ndata,type="S",sizes = 5,nsigmas=3.0, plot = FALSE)
summary(qccobj)
```

and for some reason the summary isn't the sd, LCL or UCL;

```
Call:
qcc(data = ndata, type = "S", sizes = 5, nsigmas = 3, plot = FALSE)

S chart for ndata 

Summary of group statistics:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-3.1064844 -0.6892027 -0.0246612 -0.0349110  0.6090715  2.9194738 

Group sample size:  5
Number of groups:  1000
Center of group statistics:  -0.03491101
Standard deviation:  NA 

Control limits:
 LCL UCL
```

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the qcc code on github [here](https://github.com/luca-scr/qcc/blob/42db25ba694011cb5d0827ec5ea4cc24b38d71b1/R/qcc.R). Or enter `qcc::summary.qcc` in the console to print the `summary` method in `qcc`. It will tell you what the code prints to the console as the summary.
Note that the limits are a parameter to pass to the `qcc` function and you do not do so in your example. That's why there are no values printed for UCL and LCL in the summary.
`qcc` either takes limits or the `std.dev` as parameters. Not both.
You could write your own summary method.